# JMSSerializerBundle. no control over third party meta data

Tags: serialization, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.0, jmsserializerbundle

I have two entities I wish to serialize with the JMSSerializerBundle. The `Music` Entity has a mapping-file with `exclusion_policy: NONE`.

The `Music` entity has a field of the entity `User` from `FOSUserBundle`. The `User` entity has a mapping-file with `exclusion_policy: ALL` with a few fields set to `expose: true`, so they will be serialized.

The problem is, the `User` field gets fully serialized. It does not matter if I change the mapping-file of the `User` entity.

This is how it looks:

```
#My/Bundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.Music.yml
xxx\xxx\Entity\Music:
    exclusion_policy: NONE

#My/Bundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.User.yml
xxx\xxx\Entity\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
        username:
            expose: true
        username_canonical:
            exclude: true
        email:
            exclude: true
        email_canonical:
            exclude: true
        enabled:
            exclude: true
        salt:
            exclude: true
        password:
            exclude: true
        last_login:
            exclude: true
        confirmation_token:
            exclude: true
        password_requested_at:
            exclude: true
        groups:
            exclude: true
        locked:
            exclude: true
        expired:
            exclude: true
        expires_at:
            exclude: true
        roles:
            expose: true
        credentials_expired:
            exclude: true
        credentials_expired_at:
            exclude: true
```

Why does it not refer to it's own mapping file? Or am I mistaken somewhere?

### What have I tried thusfar

I have read the third party meta data documentation. It simply says to add a new directory in my serializer service. I have done that, but I have to extend the `FOS\UserBundle\Entity` class, and that also does not have access to the parent protected fields I'm trying to exclude.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I  bet `xxx\xxx\Entity\User:` refers to your **own namespace and class**.

If it is, it is the **wrong** way to do.

The rules must be applied to the class where the properties live.

Given the property you exposed in your configuration, I guess you're using `FOSUserBundle`.

Therefore, you must apply your rules on `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`.

Then you need to add a `JMSSerializer` config to indicate where the serializer metadata live for the given namespace.

It should look like:

```
jms_serializer:
  metadata:
    auto_detection: true
    directories:
      FOSUserBundle:
        namespace_prefix: "FOS\\UserBundle"
        path: "@YourUserBundle/Resources/config/serializer/fos"
```

In `fos/` directory you should have Model.User.yml

With something like:

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
  exclusion_policy: ALL
  properties:
    id:
      expose: true
      groups: [list, details]
    username:
      expose: true
      groups: [details]
    email:
      expose: true
      groups: [me]
    roles:
      expose: true
      groups: [details]
```

---

Details:

When applying rules to the Serializer through metadata, the Serializer looks for the property which are **declared** inside the class which is **defined** in the Metadata.

Example:

```
class Foo {
     protected $foo;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
     protected $bar;
}
```

Your metadata will look like this:

```
Foo:
  exclusion_policy: ALL
  properties:
      foo: 
          expose: true

Bar:
  exclusion_policy: ALL
  properties:
      bar: 
          expose: true
```

**THE EXAMPLE BELOW IS NOT THE CORRECT WAY TO DO**

```
Bar:
  exclusion_policy: ALL
  properties:
      foo: 
          expose: true
      bar: 
          expose: true
```

if you do this, only the rules on the property `bar` will be applied (and exposed).

Comment: So I can remove the mapping for MyBundle/Entity/User which extends FOSUserBundle/Entity/User?

Comment: well, it depends, you need to remove it only if you're not trying to apply rules on property of your own. If you extended the User Model/Entity and added properties, you should keep it but include only the property which are defined your own `User` class.

Comment: @tolgap yeah most likely for every modification you make to the metadata.

Comment: Let me do your modifications, and if it works I'll accept it for my question.

Comment: Sorry to raise the specter of this question and answer, but I'm noticing that `directories` and `auto_detection` don't appear to work together. If I try to override the location where JMS looks for the third-party metadata, it won't apply it. But if I place that same metadata in the default/expected path and comment out the directory configuration in `jms_serializer` it does get applied. I'm assuming the two should work in tandem?

Comment: Why couldnt this information just be included in the official docs.... took me to long to find this

Comment: @Chris, feel free to make a PR ;)

Comment: If I use this, do I have to change all my annotations to yaml configurations as well?

Comment: I was having problems excluding properties from FOS\UserBundle\Model\User and finally I discovered you should define the properties as it is defined in User class. So $plainPassword and others should be defined in the yml using camelCase as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem that I was getting the serializer in a wrong way. You need `JMSSerializerBundle` and use the service for configuration to take effect.

So instead of:

```
//In controller we can use $this instead of $container
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer'); //JMSSerializerBundle
```

I used:

```
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build(); //JMSSerializer
```

Using the first way will load your configuration. Since I'm using `Propel`, I needed to ignore all `BaseObject` fields:

```
#app/config.yml
jms_serializer:
metadata:
    auto_detection: true
    directories:
        Propel:
            namespace_prefix: ""
            path: "@MySupporterBundle/Resources/config/serializer"
```

Note that `BaseObject` has no namespace and you need the following packages for this to work (bugged before metadata 1.2):

```
        "jms/serializer": "0.12.*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle" : "0.12.*@dev",
        "jms/metadata" : "1.3.*",
```

So I made this file:

```
#My/SupporterBundle/Resources/config/serializer/BaseObject.yml
BaseObject:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
```

and for specific objects(in Model namespace) you need files (with default namespace as My/OtherBundle):

> My/OtherBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Model.om.BaseClass.yml
>   My/OtherBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Model.Class.yml

Note: You need to clear cache when creating new serializer files