# JMSSerializer only FOSUser class properties exposed

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, jms-serializer

I've a custom User Class which extends from the FOSUser Model:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;

/**
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
```

**My problem is: The Abstract properties from the FOSUser Model are exposed, but the properties in the custom extended class not.**

To expose the properties I've two yaml files:
1) MyBundle/../Resources/config/serializer/fos/Model.User.yml
2) SecurityBundle/../Resource/config/serializer/Entity.User.yml

My custom User class has a property $name. Which should be exposed by my .yaml file:

```
ErwineEberhard\SecurityBundle\Entity\User:
    exclusion_policy: none
    properties:
        name:
            expose: true
            groups: [list, details]
```

Doctrine compels me to add a `$id` in the exteded class. The `$id` is only exposed when I add `* @ExclusionPolicy("all")` in my custom User class.
When I add @Expose to name, no differences.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: You should use only one configuration (annotation, xml or yaml), not both. And after each change you should remove content of ``cache`` directory (cause mostly it doesn't refresh after change in serialization configuration)

Comment: When I remove `@ExclusionPolicy("all")`, the id is also not exposed.

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960141/jmsserializerbundle-no-control-over-third-party-meta-data/12961994#12961994